# Django CMS: Custom plugin preview in editor escaping some characters

Tags: html, django, editor, special-characters, django-cms

I made a custom plugin for Django CMS, and as is the default behavior, the preview icon of the text field showed the returned value of the model's `__unicode__(self)` as the icon in the WYSIWYG view of the editor:

[image: "Test email"]

(where "Email address" is the name of the custom plugin.) However, if the `__unicode__(self)` method of the plugin returns anything with characters such as `'`, `&`, or `< >`, they get escaped in the preview:

[image: "Test person&#39]

I'm pretty sure the preview uses the alt text property of the plugin instance. The closest thing to people having the same issue I can find is [this report](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1159), as well as [this suggested fix](https://github.com/hpoul/django-cms/commit/b1e1d981d16edc3f3dfaaa5123bbfbfb78e9e029), but neither solution causes any change in the alt text behavior, as far as I can tell.

Basically, even though the plugin's output on the actual page isn't affected, I'd like to be able to display characters like `'`, `&`, `<`, and `>`in the editor preview. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [mark output as safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) using django helper method.

Example:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

...

def __unicode__(self):
     ... do stuff ...
     return mark_safe(output)
```